# Global variable in jquery not giving output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to declare value in global variable that I pull from data attribute. But on test script I am able to print on console but when I use it on page its giving undefined in console. Here is the jquery script I came up with.

```
var PClevel;
$(document).ready(function() {
var array = [];
$(".proimg").slice(0,3).each(function() {
    array.push($(this).data("pid"));
    PClevel = ("["+array.join(",")+"]");
});
});
console.log(PClevel);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wq3tqkzo/

Can anyone advise please why its not printing the output on live page. I have jquery library available on it. Or can anyone advise if I can have similar function in pure javascript.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it ?

Comment: yes I did. I changed the way to declare global variable on page, but its still not giving me output in console. on jsfiddle its showing me as required.

Comment: try
window.PCLevel = yourvalue;

Comment: What is `$(".proimg").slice(0,3).each` supposed to be doing? That seems like an odd way to limit the selection. `$(".proimg:lt(4)")` would be more natural IMHO

Comment: @Yaman yes I did that as well. I declared as window.PCLevel on top first, and than updated below with the value but its still not giving result

Comment: Running your fiddle I got [TDFM6,TD0307,TD5202-6]

Comment: The fiddle is currently running the logic 'onLoad'.  If you change it to either be in head or body you will see that the fiddle breaks.

Comment: @Yaman that is because jsFiddle is wrapping the whole JS section in an onload function which makes it *look like* it works. Look at the source code and youll see it ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are logging the variable outside of the document ready.  It will not be populated until the document ready runs, which will be after that console.log runs.  Move it inside the doc ready.